# Android Animation: Fading in bottom to top

Tags: android, xml, animation, fade

I would like my image to fade in so that different parts of the image would fade in at different speeds to make it appear that it is fading in from the bottom first.

All animations I've seen has the entire image fade in at the same time. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried to create custom view with partial fading support and apply PropertyAnimation? Or create transparent partially faded overlay and apply animation to it (e.g. scaling)?

Answer (score 0):

You've to write your custom animation classes.
Checkout this [animations-link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) for those who visit this question looking for solution.
From above link you'll get idea how to write and customise your animation.
Hope this helps